# Show topology generated by $B = \{ [a,b) \setminus K : a < b \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{(a,b) : a<b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ isn't metrizable

Tags: general-topology

where $K=\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

I tried taking an open set in the generated topology: $S = [-1,1) \setminus K$ and want to show that any open ball centered in $0$ is not contained in $S$.

This is easy with the standard metric, but I need to get proof for all possible metrics.

How can we prove this?

Comment: You could try showing that the space does not have a topological property that all metrizable spaces have, rather than trying to consider all possible metrics.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Show that this space is separable but not second countable, and recall that every separable metric space is second countable. (If you’ve seen the Sorgenfrey line, also known as the reals with the lower limit topology, and learned something about its properties, you might find it useful to recognize that this space contains a subspace homeomorphic to the Sorgenfrey line.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea: Note that all metric spaces are regular (indeed normal and Hausdorff). Now, observe that $K$ is closed in this topology, but if we take open sets $0\in U$ and $K\subseteq V$. Then the open set $V$ must contain little intervals $(a,b)\subseteq V$ around each $1/n \in K$. The open set $U$ must contain at least an interval $[0,\epsilon)\setminus K \subseteq U$. If we choose $1/n < \epsilon$, then the interval around $1/n$ intersects $ [0,\epsilon)\setminus K$ non-trivially. It follows that the space is not regular, and therefore not a metric space.